# R - How to make a click on webpage using rvest or rcurl

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl, rvest

I want to download data from [this webpage](http://www.tradingeconomics.com/)

The data can be easily scraped with `rvest`.

The code maybe like this :

```
library(rvest)
library(pipeR)
url <- "http://www.tradingeconomics.com/"
css <-     "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_defaultUC1_CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1_GridView1"

data <- url %>>%
  html() %>>%
  html_nodes(css) %>>%
  html_table()
```

But there is a problem for webpages like this.

There is a `+` button to show the data of all the countries, but the default is just data of 50 countries.

So if I use the code, I can just scrape data of 50 countries.

The `+` button is made in `javascript`, so I want to know if there is a way in `R` to click the button and then scrape the data.

Comment: An alternative approach to @hrbrmstr's suggestion is to use RSelenium, which will allow you to automate an interactive browser session.

Comment: @Thomas I will also try the RSelenium way to do it, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sometimes it's better to attack the problem at the ajax web-request level. For this site, you can use Chrome's dev tools and watch the requests. To build the table (the whole table, too) it makes a `POST` to the site with various ajax-y parameters. Just replicate that, do a bit of data-munging of the response and you're good to go:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

res <- POST("http://www.tradingeconomics.com/",
            encode="form",
            user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.50 Safari/537.36"),
            add_headers(`Referer`="http://www.tradingeconomics.com/",
                        `X-MicrosoftAjax`="Delta=true"),
            body=list(
              `ctl00$AjaxScriptManager1$ScriptManager1`="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$defaultUC1$CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$defaultUC1$CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1$LinkButton1",
              `__EVENTTARGET`="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$defaultUC1$CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1$LinkButton1",
              `srch-term`="",
              `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$defaultUC1$CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1$GridView1$ctl01$DropDownListCountry`="top",
              `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$defaultUC1$CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1$ParameterContinent`="",
              `__ASYNCPOST`="false"))


res_t <- content(res, as="text")
res_h <- paste0(unlist(strsplit(res_t, "\r\n"))[-1], sep="", collapse="\n")

css <- "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_defaultUC1_CurrencyMatrixAllCountries1_GridView1"

tab <- html(res_h) %>% 
  html_nodes(css) %>%
  html_table() 

tab[[1]]$COUNTRIESWORLDAMERICAEUROPEASIAAUSTRALIAAFRICA

glimpse(tab[[1]]
```

Another alternative would have been to use RSelenium to go to the page, click the "+" and then scrape the resultant table.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, next I will try to go the RSelenium way to do it. And I will share it here after that. Thanks again.

Comment: I know it's been a year, but how do you find info about the ajax content that is sent ?

Comment: "Developer Tools" in any browser or a tool like BurpProxy