# Submit form with checkboxes using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Is it possible to check a checkbox using the rvest set_values() function? In the example below the "form" object is a nested list that has the entry "fields" where "maillist" is a list with the entry "checked" that is NULL for unchecked, but how can it be checked using set_values?

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
url <- "http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_CHECKBOX.html"
session <- html_session(url)
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(form, maillist = "checked")
results <- submit_form(session, filled_form)
content(results$response, "text")
```

An obvious workaround is that clicking the checkbox and submitting the form in a browser shows the value of maillist as "on", but this information might not always be known for other forms.

Comment: see perhaps here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185501/r-language-how-to-make-a-click-on-webpage-using-rvest-or-rcurl

Comment: and perhaps this PR: https://github.com/hadley/rvest/pull/132